# Unable to download a CSV file using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am unable to download a CSV file using Selenium Python. The download dialog keep popping up and the file does not get downloaded.

The following is the dialog box I get upon downloading

[image: Dialog Box on downloading]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from BasePage import BasePage
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.support.select  import Select
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui      import WebDriverWait
import os
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())

fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "test/csv")

# fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Comment: Did you try handling it as an alert box and accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `test/csv`, it should be `text/csv` instead.

If this is not working, the file might have a different mime type, try the following:

```
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream")
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This works - fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream")

Comment: @Chiragverma Consider validating the answer as correct.